# Multipeer connectivity auto connect

Tags: ios, swift, multipeer-connectivity

I'm trying to get my head around Apple's multipeer connectivity, and I got it working in a predictable way now. Given the enormous amounts of questions here and elsewhere on the web, that is a victory in itself...

So what I have right now is:

two devices discovering their shared network. By selecting Device B in the browser, Device A connects to Device B and the game can start.

**What I actually want to establish, is that nobody actually has to do anything to connect to the network of my app.**

I don't want my users to tap a name in a browser. I just want all the devices on that network to discover the network, and connect to it.

Is that possible at all? Is there one device that should be the leader/host?

thanks for your insight

Comment: that is a pity. is that a security issue? an omission?

Comment: Not sure if this answer my question, but I found this:
https://peterfennema.nl/ios-multipeer-2/ @Paulw11 what do you think?

Comment: Actually, it looks like I was wrong. You can invite a peer and that peer can accept the invitation without user intervention https://developer.apple.com/documentation/multipeerconnectivity/mcnearbyserviceadvertiserdelegate/1406971-advertiser?language=objc